# SPOTIFY API authorization using REACT.JS

Tags: reactjs, spotify

I'm trying to connect a Spotify API, everything is working, playlist are being gathered etc..
My main problem is how can I get the authorization from the SPOTIFY login.
the code below is my login code.

```
const Login = () => {
  const CLIENT_ID = 'e01c2f1b6e2d4e92bfe2c04ae2893c7f';
  const REDIRECT_URI = 'http://localhost:3000';
  const AUTH_ENDPOINT = 'https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize';
  const RESPONSE_TYPE = 'token';



  return (
    <div
      className="container d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center"
      style={{ minHeight: "100vh" }}
    >
      <div className="position-relative">
        <div className="card bg-light p-4 border-0 rounded-3 shadow">
          <div className="card-body text-center">
            <a href={`${AUTH_ENDPOINT}?client_id=${CLIENT_ID}&redirect_uri=${REDIRECT_URI}&response_type=${RESPONSE_TYPE}`} className="btn btn-success">
              Login with Spotify
            </a>
            {/* <button onClick={fetchTrackData}>Fetch User Profile</button> */}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

When I click on LOGIN it redirects to spotify authorization but then it just show a connection refused and console displays this: non-JS module files deprecated.

Already tried finding the solution in numberous videos and chatGPT,
I also think the spotify authorization method has changed in the past few months thats why it's different.
My main goal here is to get authorization to use the react-spotify-web-playback library with need the spotify premium login.